# Cython setup.py to install compiled extension

Tags: python, cython, distutils

How do you write a setup.py to compile .pyx files in an arbitrary location and install the compiled code in another arbitrary location? For example `dirA/spam.pyx` to `build/dirB/spam.so`?

Comment: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html ?

Comment: By default cython builds to `build/lib-linux-<arch>-<ver>/spam-cpython-<ver>.so`.  I asked because I couldn't get it to install it elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [distutils documentation](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#install-index), you can build any compiled python modules in an arbitrary location using the command line option `--build-base`, e.g.:

```
python setup.py build --build-base=/build/dirB
```

If you want to keep the default build directory, but install to a custom location, you should use one of the options `--user` `--home`, `--prefix`, `--exec-prefix`, `--install-base` or `--install-platbase`

Finally, if you just want the `.so` file in the current directory, use the option `--inplace`